# Passing login information with the url doesnt work

Tags: php

I am trying to create user specific link into my Wordpress website which will looks like

`<a href="http://example.com/dir/index.php?email=un@example.com&pass=foo!"> link </a>`

When user click on the `link` auto login into `http://example.com/dir/index.php` *(which is outside of Wordpress).*

**Here is what index.php or login page looks like:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="") {
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if($row['password']==md5($upass)) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
    else {
    ?>
    <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: The `email=un@example.com&pass=password!`, especially the `pass=password!` is not a good idea. You should not pass a password via `$_GET`

Comment: @Rasclatt that is just an example

Comment: This is also not a good idea: `md5($upass)`

Comment: Also, is this code inside Wordpress? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: No its a separate normal php code

Comment: Oh gotcha. Well if you are infact going to pass the user and pass in a click, then you need to check for `$_GET['email']`, not `$_POST['email']` (and password)

Comment: Even if it's an example, it's a bad example.  People come to StackOverflow looking to solve problems; if they come across this posting, they might get the mistaken impression that this is a good idea.  Why not provide an example that uses POST?

Comment: @jdigital my bad thank you for letting me know

Comment: Did you try it with `$_GET`?

Comment: @Rasclatt yes but no luck, I only make these changes `<form method="GET" ` and `$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
 $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pass']);` is that right?

Comment: I thought you were trying to pass via a link? Or did you switch to  a form?

Comment: @Rasclatt yes i want to pass via a link but show me  login form. I doesn't login

Comment: Ok so just so I get it right, you have site A that has a form that sends to site B remotely to log in?

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks for the help. I have site A that has a link not a form that sends to site B remotely to log in( Site B has a login form i want to pass that, via a link coming from A. without entering username and password ).

Comment: @Rasclatt All the code i listed on my question is in site B site A contains only a link

Comment: Ok I got you. I will write an answer that you can try but I will be able to do it a bit later

Comment: Cool, thanks alot i will wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you are trying, you may want to do a more complex process which would be something using AJAX, cURL (I am using a cURL library), and MySQLi.

**Explanation:**

Your referring page contains a button that contains just the username or unique ID in a `data` field. When user clicks the username button (retrieved from the user table, *rasclatt in this case*), ajax fires, queries the local database just to verify that the user is legit. If good, will send a cURL query to your second site. The second site will generate a token (could first check that the username is valid first), then save that into a database along with the username. Then, it will send back the new token where Site A will then, on success of the ajax, jump to the Site B with the token filled in. Last (not illustrated here), SiteB will then get the token and search the token table to verify it's valid (you could send back the username so there has to be two pieces to match against). If valid it will then use the stored username to create a user session for SiteB. What I have works but would need error reporting and all that.

Anyway, there are lots of ways to do it, but this is probably a more simplistic way to do it:

**Site A - CLIENT SIDE: login.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<h2>User Name</h2>
<div class="remoteLogin" data-username="rasclatt">rasclatt<div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".remoteLogin").click(function(e) {
    var username    =   jQuery(this).data('username');
     jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'verify.php',
                data: { username: username },
                success: function(response) {
                    var user    =   JSON.parse(response);
                    if(user.servertoken != undefined)
                        window.location.href    =   "http://www.SiteB.com/login.php?token="+user.servertoken;
                },
                error: function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Site A - SERVER SIDE: verify.php**

```
class   cURL
    {
        public      $response;
        public      $ch;
        protected   $sendHeader;

        protected   $PostFields;

        private     $query;

        public  function    __construct($query = '')
            {
                $this->sendHeader   =   false;
                $this->query        =   $query;
                // Remote Connect
                $this->initConnect();
                if(!empty($this->query)) {
                        if(!is_array($this->query))
                            $this->response =   $this->Connect($this->query);
                        else
                            $this->encode();
                    }
            }

        public  function initConnect()
            {
                $this->ch   = curl_init();
                return $this;
            }

        public  function SendPost($array = array())
            {
                $this->PostFields['payload']    =   $array;
                $this->PostFields['query']      =   http_build_query($array);
                return $this;
            }

        public  function setAttr($attr = false,$val = false)
            {
                if(!empty($attr))
                    curl_setopt($this->ch, $attr, $val);

                return $this;
            }

        public  function Connect($_url,$deJSON = true)
            {
                curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_url);
                curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                if(strpos($_url,"https://") !== false) {
                        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,2);
                        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
                    }

                if(!empty($this->PostFields['payload'])) {
                        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($this->PostFields['payload']));
                        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->PostFields['query']);
                    }

                if(!empty($this->sendHeader))
                    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56');

                $decode     =   curl_exec($this->ch);
                $_response  =   ($deJSON)? json_decode($decode, true) : $decode;
                $error      =   curl_error($this->ch);

                curl_close($this->ch);
                return (empty($error))? $_response: $error;
            }

        public  function emulateBrowser()
            {
                $this->sendHeader   =   true;
                return $this;
            }

        public  function encode($_filter = 0)
            {
                foreach($this->query as $key => $value) {
                        $string[]   =   urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
                    }

                if($_filter == true)
                    $string =   array_filter($string);

                return implode("&",$string);
            }
    }


if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $mysqli     =   new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $stmt       =   $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as count from users where `username` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result     =   $stmt->get_result();
    $row        =   $result->fetch_assoc();

    if($row['count'] == 1) {
            $apikey     =   'b5714832ac3444be183252c6ac260f87';
            $cURL       =   new cURL();
            $response   =   $cURL->connect("http://www.SiteB.com/api.php?apikey={$apikey}&username=".urlencode($_POST['username'])."&action=get_token",false);

            echo $response;
        }

    exit;
}
```

**Site B - SERVER SIDE: api.php**

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'get_token') {
        if(!empty($_REQUEST['apikey'])) {
                if($_REQUEST['apikey'] != 'b5714832ac3444be183252c6ac260f87') {
                        echo json_encode(array("error"=>"key invalid"));
                        exit;
                    }
                else {
                        $token  =   base64_encode(microtime().mt_rand().".".$_REQUEST['username']);
                        // write to database the $token
                        // write username to database in same row, different column
                        echo json_encode(array("servertoken"=>urlencode($token)));
                        exit;
                    }
            }
    }
```

One note to all this, you will want to make sure that the user is able to do this action using Wordpress' version of checking user session.

Comment: How can i make `remoteLogin` div clickable and how can i add the first code that into wordpress page -- the first part ? i tried add it to wordpress page using  `<button onclick="function()">rasclatt</button>` but it doesnt do anything?. You're awsome

Comment: To make it clickable in wordpress (the div is already clickable, but in wordpress,  it's slightly different to get it to work there), you will likely have to change the jQuery everywhere it says `$` to `jQuery` so: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` and `jQuery(this)` etc...I will modify.